# PHP remove duplicate instances of dates in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried various permutations of `array_unique`, and have searched other generic questions here on removing duplicate values from an array, but I can't quite set upon the answer I need.  I have an array being passed of dates and values, and only want to view the DATE value once per date.

I'm using this for a Google chart and only want the date labels to show up once for each date.  And I don't want to remove it entirely, because I want to be able to plot it on the chart.

So, an example array being passed:

```
["June 4",30],["June 4",35],["June 5",46],["June 5",38.33],["June 5",12]
```

And how I want it:

```
["June 4",30],["",35],["June 5",46],["",38.33],["",12]
```

Ideas?

Comment: Create an associative array from date label to value? That way if you add two entries with the same date label, you will end up with only one entry and thus only one value.

Comment: I would restructure array like array("June 4"=>array(30,35)) and so on...

Comment: Do you already have actual example code of this. The way you have isn't going to work the way you want it with it's current structure. How do you get the dates and values to begin with?

Comment: Since he's feeding the data into Google Charts, restructuring the data is probably not practical... he'd be restructuring, processing, and then converting back to this format anyways for charting.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution for your problem, though I would recommend a re-construction as Patashu & Nikola R stated.

```
$untrimmed = [["June 4",30],["June 4",35],["June 5",46],["June 5",38.33],["June 5",12]];
$trimmed = stripDates($untrimmed);

function stripDates($dates) {
    foreach( $dates as $key=>$date ) {
        if ($key>0) {
            if ($date[0] === $dates[$key-1][0]) {
                $dates[$key][0] = "";
            } else if($dates[$key-1][0] === "") {
                for ($i = $key-1; $i > -1; $i--) {
                   if ($date[0] === $dates[$i][0]) $dates[$key][0] = "";
                   if ($dates[$key] != "") break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $dates;
}

// Note: This would require dates to be added chronically
//Output: ["June 4",30],["",35],["June 5",46],["",38.33],["",12]
```

I would recommend something like this:

```
$unconstructed = [["June 4",30],["June 4",35],["June 5",46],["June 5",38.33],["June 5",12]];
$constructed = constructAssoc($unconstructed);

function constructAssoc($dates) {
    $constructed = array();
    foreach( $dates as $index=>$date ) {
        if (!array_key_exists($date[0], $constructed)) {
            $constructed[$date[0]] = array("index"=>$index, "value"=>$date[1]);
        } else {
            array_push($constructed[$date[0], ["index"=>$index,"value"=>$date[1]]);
        }
    }
    return $constructed;
}

//Output: ["June 4"=> [["index"=>0, "value"=>30], ["index"=>1, "value"=>35]], "June 5"=>[["index"=>2, "value"=>46], ["index"=>3, "value"=>38.33], ["index"=>4, "value"=>12]]]
```

Note: Added index in recommended solution if a more accurate re-construction is needed.

Comment: The nested loop in this solution will start to take a long time if the data set gets very large - it's an O(n^2) algorithm

Comment: For your recommended solution, how does he get it back to the format he needs for charting?

Comment: Added a break solution for better performance. And for the second comment, it would not be possible to get them in the same position, unless you added each index inside each value.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the data to feed into a google chart, I'm assuming that you know exactly what you need as far as output data. There's already some suggestions above for better ways to structure the data, but that probably won't work directly for a google chart.

How about this?

```
$data = [["June 4",30],["June 4",35],["June 5",46],["June 5",38.33],["June 5",12]];
$found = array();
foreach ($data as $i => $x) {
    if (in_array($x[0], $found)) {
        $data[$i][0] = '';
    } else {
        $found[] = $x[0];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

Basically, it's just building a list of dates that it's already seen. We loop through the data, and check if we've seen the date... if we have, we clear it from the data, otherwise we save it to the list so it'll be cleared next time.

Here's an alternate solution that only checks for duplicate dates that are *consecutive*, unlike the first solution that will remove *all* duplicates. This is probably closer to what you need for charting:

```
$data = [["June 4",30],["June 4",35],["June 5",46],["June 5",38.33],["June 5",12]];
$last = '';
foreach ($data as $i => $x) {
    if ($x[0] == $last) {
        $data[$i][0] = '';
    } else {
        $last = $x[0];
    }
}
print_r($data);
```

In this case, we're just keeping track of the last date we've seen... and if our new date matches that, we clear it.